# vertically alignment of a text inside a button with an image

Tags: html, css, vertical-alignment

In this CodePen you can see a `<button>` with an image and text inside (`<span>`). The problem is when the text got multiline. The second line of text is not immediately close to the first line and a big space appears (taking in count the height of the `<img>`).

**My code ([on CodePen](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/jaKqJe)):**

```css
button {
  width: 300px;
}
img {
  vertical-align: middle;
}
```

```html
<button>
  <img src="http://lorempixel.com/50/50/" />
  <span> Some Text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text</span>
</button>
```

Comment: Float the `img` left

Comment: Sry but the img must be in that position, I mean, not floated to left or right because the text can be or not, so, if there is no text, the img should be centered

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use the following solution using flexbox:

```css
* {
  margin:0;
  padding:0;
  box-sizing:border-box;
}
button {
  align-items: center;
  display: flex;
  padding: 3px;
  justify-content: center;
  width: 300px;
}
button img {
  flex-shrink: 0;
  margin-right: 10px;
}
```

```html
<button>
  <img src="https://lorempixel.com/50/50/" alt="">
  <span>Some Text Some Text Some Text Some Text Some Text Some Text Some Text</span>
</button>
<button>
  <img src="https://lorempixel.com/50/50/" alt="">
  <span>Some Text</span>
</button>
<button>
  <img src="https://lorempixel.com/50/50/" alt="">
</button>
```

Comment: Sry but the img must be in that position, I mean, not floated to left or right because the text can be or not, so, if there is no text, the img should be centered

Comment: That's it, no need for vertical-align:middle. ;)

Comment: but if I took away the vertical align  the text puts below the image, and that is not the expected behavior

Comment: nice solution, but the content is not vertically aligned, try it with short text, this stick at top.

Comment: @NewJsGuy - updated the answer: now it is aligned vertically.

Answer (score 0):

can you try this 
https://codepen.io/anon/pen/qVKagg

```css
button {
  width: 300px;
  display: flex;
  text-align:left;
}

img {
  vertical-align: middle;
  margin-right:5px;
}
```

```html
<button>
<img src="http://lorempixel.com/50/50/" />
<span> Some Text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text</span>
</button>
```

Comment: Yep, tryed and not worked!  try it with less text, do it just with 'Some Text', and the text will be sticked at the top of the button and not in the middle

Answer (score 0):

Try to do it like this way. There are other methods also, but this one is simple.

```css
button {
  width: 300px;
}
button img {
  float:left;
  width:20%;
}
button span {
  float:right;
  width:80%;
}
```

```html
<button>
  <img src="http://lorempixel.com/50/50/" />
  <span> Some Text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text</span>
</button>
```